# How to know that there is no content to show in Web View anymore in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am creating a paymnet page inside a Web View in Xamarin forms to work on both andoid and IOS devices.Right now i am pushing a new page and on whole page there is a Web View. I pass my paymet page url to the web view Source and pass all the necessary details as a Post Method in bytes see that link for more details about this method([Clik here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl(java.lang.String,%20byte[]))).
My problem is when the paymet is complete web page becomes blank and my whole page screen becomes blank. I dont have any event to know when there is no content to show in my web view so that i can Pop my current page from the NavigationStack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont have any event to know when there is no content to show in my web view so that i can Pop my current page from the NavigationStack.

When the paymet is complete on the webview, the call back `url` must be different than before.  You can compare it with something like `"payment/success=1"` in the event of  [Webview.Navigated](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Navigated/)

```
webview.Navigated += (object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e) => {
    if (e.Url.StartsWith("xxxx")) {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    } ;
};
```

Comment: Yes ,you are right but i have to rely solely on the call back url.